# Facebook Canvas App developing without SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

Facebook recently changed the security settings on Account Configs, now there is no more an option to force, or not, an application to use HTTPS protocol.

Therefore, it isn't possible to do a App without a SSL key. Previously we could just don't fill **Secure Canvas URL** field, and access the canvas app through the HTTP protocol. But now, without the option in the security user config, the facebook app keeps redirecting to the HTTPS protocol.

So, there is some workaround for this ?

Comment: You will need to use SSL. Your SSL certificate doesn’t have to be “official”, however – it can be a self-signed one, since only your browser has to accept it. (That’s what I do when developing locally all the time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CBroe says, you need SSL.

There are 2 things you need in my opinion:

#### A webserver with SSL.

IF you're in OSX and you run Apache, this tutorial really helps:
http://blog.andyhunt.info/2011/11/26/apache-ssl-on-max-osx-lion-10-7/, plus you might want to add your certificate as a trusted (root?) certificate, or certificate authority. (I'm not very well versed in this)
The only caveat I found, specially for Chrome, is that when you're generating the Certificate Request File, under Common Name place "localhost" or the host you're using for development. This last caveat should be similar in Windows, since it's a browser requirement that the certificate common name matches the actual host. Browsers like Firefox allows you to permanently trust a certificate, thus avoiding all the certificate installation on the OS and trusting.

#### A proxy app

proxy-like app to act as a man in the middle and decode the encrypted information, in order to see the actual requests and response being sent and received from the server. There should be other software, but the one I use and love is Charles Proxy, which can do this and tons more.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ramiro.

One off question. Are you one of the guys who supported the Gaia Framework for Flash ? I think remember you from there.

Comment: hahah!! indeed! I still use the same picture for almost everything :D

Comment: ahhaha, yeah, 4 years passed and I remembered ahahah, you helped me a lot there, thanks again!